# Code First:Should I put the data annotation "Required" in a navigation property?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations, code-first

I have a question about how I define the entries when I work with "Code First".

I am defining the following class with these data annotations:

```
public class Producto
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductoID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parque"),Required]
    public int FKParque { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FKParque"), Required]
    public virtual Parque Parque { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

The question is:Should I put the data annotation "Required"  in the navigation property "Parque"?
If I put the data annotation, when I try to do:

```
using (MiContexto contexto = new MiContexto()) {
            Producto nuevoProducto = new Producto();
            nuevoProducto.Nombre = "nuevo";
            nuevoProducto.FKParque = 1;

            contexto.Productos.Add(nuevoProducto);

            contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

An error occurs because the navigable property is null and is marked as required.

What would be the right approach?

Sorry if my English is not very good.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think placing the `required` attribute on the `FKParque` is sufficient.  The navigation property isn't populated until the object is saved/retrieved from the database, so could potentially be null, even if the foreign key can't be.